# I am trying to access DocuSign API using JWT Approach. I got the private and public key, how to get the certificate?

Tags: jwt, certificate, docusignapi

I am trying to access DocuSign API using JWT Approach. I got the private and public key, how to get the certificate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look here at our guide on how to get a JWT token: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/jwt-get-token/

You can also have a look at specific code examples that all include JWT authorisation here: https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/overview

Comment: Thank you. I resolved this converted from pkcs1 to pkcs 8 using open ssl and then used a java program to read the private key as a string and then subsequently sign the jwt token...

Answer (score 0):

The public key that you download from DocuSign is the certificate. But you don't need it, you only need the private key. Use it for creating the JWT for the JWT grant flow.

Comment: Thank you. I resolved this converted from pkcs1 to pkcs 8 using open ssl and then used a java program to read the private key as a string and then subsequently sign the jwt token...